# I want to switch to another view when tapped on my tableviewcell

Tags: ios7.1

I want to switch to another view when tapped on my tableviewcell inside my dropdown table. It must only happen for one section and i want to do it programmatically. Can someone please help ??
 Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the UITableViewDelegate in your view controller.

Then you have the callback tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:.

This method is called when the user selects a row and it gives you the index path of that (that contains the row and the section).

With this information you can react to the touch.